# Count time spend on site each day

Tags: php, authentication

I searched the internet, but I found nothing relevant.

I have this `login.log` file that I will import in MYSQL. And I want to count the number of minutes each user spend each day. My plan is to use triggers after each login to insert time to a table and when there is a logout, a trigger to minus previous login time from `now()` and count that in a new table.

What do you think of this approach?
Minutes would be equal to `((logout time)-(login time)) + ((logout time)-(login time))` and so on and on. Are there any other ways of doing this better or similar?

Here is what the table looks like:

Each user can login/logout multiple times throughout the day (`connect=login=enter-room`, `disconnect=logout=quit`).

This is a sample of the log file:

> 5/30/2017 12:00 Anonymous d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 connect
>   5/30/2017 12:00 user46172 d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 login
>   5/30/2017 12:00 user46172 d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 enter room -
>   5/30/2017 12:00 Anonymous 72d76b17-a8f0-442a-a860-49483bf72a6e connect
>   5/30/2017 12:00 guest5528 72d76b17-a8f0-442a-a860-49483bf72a6e login
>   5/30/2017 12:00 guest5528 72d76b17-a8f0-442a-a860-49483bf72a6e enter room -
>   5/30/2017 12:00 guest7632 0321676a-f22f-4d2f-acca-b8759e349ab6 disconnect
>   5/30/2017 12:01 user46172 d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 quit room -
>   5/30/2017 12:01 user46172 d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 logout
>   5/30/2017 12:02 jdoe d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 login
>   5/30/2017 12:02 jdoe d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 logout
>   5/30/2017 12:02 jdoe d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 login
>   5/30/2017 12:02 jdoe d4dfa596-f02d-40b4-b059-eff86dfe6492 enter room -
>   5/30/2017 12:02 Anonymous 186e5eae-d279-4a66-b556-0fa4a5b179d4 connect

Comment: I improved the formatting of the question, some spelling/grammar and reformulated/added the topic relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing to the log? Can you insert into the table when they log in or out when the log is written to? This way you can avoid triggers, which are great until someone else takes over the code and wonders what magic is happening to manipulate the table! As long as you have all the log in and out times; you can have the query take the min(login time) and max(logout time) for each day and calculate the difference.

I have found it best to put all data into the log table and then use a query to extract what you need, even if that then is put into another 'caching' table to save on processing further down the line.

Comment: I am going to research that Phright. How to export to mysql as logs are added to the file. I am not writing to the log manually. It is created by a chat application (123flashchat) each day and updates every time there is an action